# Delete directory and all symlinks recursively

Tags: python, recursion, directory, symlink, delete-file

I tried to use `shutil` to delete a directory and all contained files, as follows:

```
import shutil
from os.path import exists
if exists(path_dir):
    shutil.rmtree(path_dir)
```

Unfortunately, my solution does not work, throwing the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '._image1.jpg'
```

A quick search showed that I'm [not alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64687047/shutil-rmtree-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-xxx) in having this problem.
In my understanding, the `rmtree` function is equivalent to the `rm -Rf $DIR` shell command - but this doesn't seem to be the case.

p.s. for reconstruction purposes. Please create a symbolic link for example using `ln -s /path/to/original /path/to/link`

Comment: Is `path_dir` a path to a symbolic link?

Comment: no,  path_dir to a directory containing various files and folders

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is strange, I have no issues with shutil.rmtree() with or without symlink under the folder to be deleted, both in windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

Anyhow try the following code. I tried it in windows 10 and Ubuntu.

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil


def delete_dir_recursion(p):
    """
    Delete folder, sub-folders and files.
    """
    for f in p.glob('**/*'):
        if f.is_symlink():
            f.unlink(missing_ok=True)  # missing_ok is added in python 3.8
            print(f'symlink {f.name} from path {f} was deleted')
        elif f.is_file():
            f.unlink()
            print(f'file: {f.name} from path {f} was deleted')
        elif f.is_dir():
            try:
                f.rmdir()  # delete empty sub-folder
                print(f'folder: {f.name} from path {f} was deleted')
            except OSError:  # sub-folder is not empty
                delete_dir_recursion(f)  # recurse the current sub-folder
            except Exception as exception:  # capture other exception
                print(f'exception name: {exception.__class__.__name__}')
                print(f'exception msg: {exception}')

    try:
        p.rmdir()  # time to delete an empty folder
        print(f'folder: {p.name} from path {p} was deleted')
    except NotADirectoryError:
        p.unlink()  # delete folder even if it is a symlink, linux
        print(f'symlink folder: {p.name} from path {p} was deleted')
    except Exception as exception:
        print(f'exception name: {exception.__class__.__name__}')
        print(f'exception msg: {exception}')


def delete_dir(folder):
    p = Path(folder)

    if not p.exists():
        print(f'The path {p} does not exists!')
        return

    # Attempt to delete the whole folder at once.
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(p)
    except Exception as exception:
        print(f'exception name: {exception.__class__.__name__}')
        print(f'exception msg: {exception}')
        # continue parsing the folder
    else:  # else if no issues on rmtree()
        if not p.exists():  # verify
            print(f'folder {p} was successfully deleted by shutil.rmtree!')
            return

    print(f'Parse the folder {folder} ...')
    delete_dir_recursion(p)

    if not p.exists():  # verify
        print(f'folder {p} was successfully deleted!')

# start
folder_to_delete = '/home/zz/tmp/sample/b'  # delete folder b
delete_dir(folder_to_delete)
```

Sample output:

We are going to delete the folder `b`.

```
.
├── 1.txt
├── a
├── b
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 1.txt -> ../1.txt
│   ├── 2
│   │   └── 21
│   │       └── 21.txt
│   ├── 3
│   │   └── 31
│   ├── 4
│   │   └── c -> ../../c
│   ├── a -> ../a
│   └── b.txt
├── c
```

```
Parse the folder /home/zz/tmp/sample/b ...
symlink a from path /home/zz/tmp/sample/b/a was deleted
symlink c from path /home/zz/tmp/sample/b/4/c was deleted
folder: 4 from path /home/zz/tmp/sample/b/4 was deleted
symlink 1.txt from path /home/zz/tmp/sample/b/1.txt was deleted
file: b.txt from path /home/zz/tmp/sample/b/b.txt was deleted
file: 21.txt from path /home/zz/tmp/sample/b/2/21/21.txt was deleted
folder: 21 from path /home/zz/tmp/sample/b/2/21 was deleted
folder: 2 from path /home/zz/tmp/sample/b/2 was deleted
folder: 1 from path /home/zz/tmp/sample/b/1 was deleted
folder: 31 from path /home/zz/tmp/sample/b/3/31 was deleted
folder: 3 from path /home/zz/tmp/sample/b/3 was deleted
folder: b from path /home/zz/tmp/sample/b was deleted
folder /home/zz/tmp/sample/b was successfully deleted!
```

Comment: I think you are quiet close. The function deletes all the files inside all folders, but does not remove the folders after the are empty

Comment: @JürgenK. what could be the issue?, I expect the empty folder will be dealt in `p.rmdir()  # time to delete an empty folder` Is there any messages? Are you testing in linux or windows?

Comment: No issue, rmdir works probably not recursive. So if there are empty folders containing another empty folders, rmdir wont work. Testing on mac

Comment: Thanks for the info I will recheck it.

Comment: @JürgenK. got the fix, now it can recursively deletes files/subfolders.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**: Underlying python bug has been fixed by [cpython#14064](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/14064), which will be part of python 3.13 (mitigation code for earlier versions below).

You are probably on Mac OSX and your directory is at least partially on a non-Mac filesystem (ie not HFS+). On those, Mac filesystem drivers automatically create binary companion files prefixed with `._` to record so-called *extended attributes* (explained in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them, but also illustrated below).

`rmtree` on systems which do not support file descriptors in `os.scandir` (like Mac OSX) now unsafely creates a list of entries and then unlinks them one by one (creating a known race-condition: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/908fd691f96403a3c30d85c17dd74ed1f26a60fd/Lib/shutil.py#L592-L621). Unfortunately two separate behaviours make this condition true every time:

1. the original file is always listed before the extended attributes one, and
2. when the original file is unlinked (`test.txt`) the meta file (`._test.txt`) is removed simultaneously.

Thus, the extended attribute file will be missing when it is its turn and throw the `FileNotFoundError` you are experiencing.

I think this bug would be best addressed by [cpython#14064](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/14064), which aims at ignoring `FileNotFoundError`s in `rmtree` generally.

## Mitigation

In the mean time you could ignore unlinking errors on those meta files with `onerror`:

```
def ignore_extended_attributes(func, filename, exc_info):
    is_meta_file = os.path.basename(filename).startswith("._")
    if not (func is os.unlink and is_meta_file):
        raise

shutil.rmtree(path_dir, onerror=ignore_extended_attributes)
```

## Show case of Mac's extended attributes

To illustrate you can create a small ExFAT disk image and mount it to `/Volumes/Untitled` with the commands

```
hdiutil create -size 5m -fs exfat test.dmg
hdiutil attach test.dmg            # mounts at /Volumes/Untitled
cd /Volumes/Untitled

mkdir test                         # create a directory to remove
cd test
touch test.txt
open test.txt                      # open the test.txt file in the standard editor
```

Just opening the file in the standard text editor creates an extended attributes file `._test.txt` and records the last access time in it:

```
/Volumes/Untitled/test $ ls -a
.          ..         ._test.txt test.txt
/Volumes/Untitled/test $ xattr test.txt
com.apple.lastuseddate#PS
```

The problem is that unlinking the original file automatically also unlinks the  companion file.

```
/Volumes/Untitled/test $ rm test.txt
/Volumes/Untitled/test $ ls -a
.          ..
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you for the Mitigation-code

Answer (score 1):

From [How to remove a directory including all its files in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756284/how-to-remove-a-directory-including-all-its-files-in-python)

```
# function that deletes all files and then folder

import glob, os

def del_folder(dir_name):
    
    dir_path = os.getcwd() +  "\{}".format(dir_name)
    try:
        os.rmdir(dir_path)  # remove the folder
    except:
        print("OSError")   # couldn't remove the folder because we have files inside it
    finally:
        # now iterate through files in that folder and delete them one by one and delete the folder at the end
        try:
            for filepath in os.listdir(dir_path):
                os.remove(dir_path +  "\{}".format(filepath))
            os.rmdir(dir_path)
            print("folder is deleted")
        except:
            print("folder is not there")
```

You can also just use the `ignore_errors` flag with [shutil.rmtree()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree).

`shutil.rmtree('/folder_name', ignore_errors=True)`
That should remove a directory with file contents.